# Wait until importing an image finishes on Alibaba Cloud

Tags: alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs

I don't understand how I can wait until importing an image finish with the aliyun cli. The official documentation describes an ["Result polling"](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/122114.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.b99.21.3f0d410a1Vsl2E) mechanism but it works only with existing resources and strings, e.g.

```
$ aliyun ecs DescribeImages --ImageName="${aliyun_image_name}" --waiter expr='TotalCount' to=1
ERROR: object 0 isn't string
```

Moreover, I don't understand how I can use the taskId from ImportImage response. There exist documentation.

Here are my steps to reproduce:

```
$ aliyun ecs ImportImage \
    --RegionId="${aliyun_region}" \
    --DiskDeviceMapping.1.OSSBucket="${aliyun_bucket_name}" \
    --DiskDeviceMapping.1.OSSObject="${aliyun_image_blob}" \
    --ImageName="${aliyun_image_name}"
{
    "ImageId": ...,
    "RegionId": ...,
    "RequestId": ...,
    "TaskId": ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$ aliyun ecs DescribeTasks --RegionId "${aliyun_region}" --TaskIds "${TaskId}"